# Upload de imagens não funciona no servidor mesmo com caminho completo

Tags: php, servidor, imagem, upload

Mesmo colocando o caminho completo e a pasta tendo permissão 777 a imagem não vai para seu destino.
O safe_mode está marcado como off e o upload de imagens está habilitado no php.ini.
Vale acrescentar que estava funcionando normalmente no localhost.

Segue o código:

```
<?php

 //Upload de arquivos
// verifica se foi enviado um arquivo
 if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0)
 {
echo "Você enviou o arquivo: <strong>" . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "</strong><br />";
echo "Este arquivo é do tipo: <strong>" . $_FILES['file']['type'] . "</strong><br />";
    echo "Seu tamanho é: <strong>" . $_FILES['file']['size'] . "</strong>   Bytes<br /><br />";

$arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$nome = $_FILES['file']['name'];

// Pega a extensao
$extensao = strrchr($nome, '.');

// Converte a extensao para mimusculo
$extensao = strtolower($extensao);

// Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
// Aqui eu enfilero as extesões permitidas e separo por ';'
// Isso server apenas para eu poder pesquisar dentro desta String
if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao))
{
    // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
    // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
    $novoNome = md5(microtime()) . $extensao;

    // Concatena a pasta com o nome
    $destino = 'http://www.lcjprojetos.com.br/admin/imgsupload/' . $novoNome;

    // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
    if( @move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  ))
    {
        echo "Arquivo salvo com sucesso em : <strong>" . $destino . "</strong><br />";
    }
    else
        echo "Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />";
}
else
    echo "Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos jpeg jpg png e gif<br />";
}
   else
  {
   echo "Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Deves percorrer o diretório usando caminhos absolutos, significa, que não podes usar `http//:site`, podes simplesmente recuar 1 diretório `../` ou mesmo recuar 1 diretório e abrir outro subdiretório nesse mesmo diretório `../outro/`, experimenta e diz se funcionou ou não.

Comment: Consegui dessa forma que você me disse,porém colocando apenas um . passou a ficar ./admin/imgsupload/ .Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Correção, os caminhos devem ser _relativos_, eu disse _absolutos_ que era exatamente o que estavas a fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize caminhos relativos, em vez de caminhos absolutos, para percorrer as pastas no diretório.

Se tiveres por exemplo:

```
-- Root
 - publico
    *uploads
    *admin
     ficheiro_responsavel_pelo_upload.php 
     ...
 - privado
    *layout
    *config
```

Deves recuar 1 diretório `../` e depois avançar outro `../uploads/`.